# How to divide by value based on a date, not total value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

The total Count for Status = "Submitted" is 2,320.

I need to calculate column `Ratio`, so column `Count` for  each `Status` need to be divided by `Count` where `Status = "Submitted"` (1,655).

But instead it divides by Total Count of `Status` = "Submitted" (2,320)
The expression for calculated column `Ratio` looks like this:

```
Ratio = DIVIDE(Number_3[Count],CALCULATE(SUM(Number_3[Count]),FILTER(Number_3,Number_3[Status] = "Submitted")))
```

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

Relationship in the model look like this:

[image]

UPDATE:

If I select fill date range then Count of Submitted will be 2,320

[image]

Update: 
.ipbx file is available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dp063gf48sbvexc/TestPredictions.pbix?dl=0  .
Its on Page 2. Query 'Number_3'

Comment: I don't understand where 2320 is coming from (vs 1655).

Comment: Its a total count of Submitted. If I select full date range then the submission number will be 2,320. I updated it in a question. Thanks

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is based on your post (maybe post a .pbix?), but it does seem odd to me that the numerator of your `DIVIDE` isn't an aggregation like the denominator is.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dp063gf48sbvexc/TestPredictions.pbix?dl=0  Its on Page 2. Query 'Number_3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator was indeed funny looking! Your `Ratio` should be a measure, not a calculated column. (Calculated columns are never affected by any slicers or filtering on your report pages.)

Delete your `Ratio` calculated column and replace it with the following measure:

```
Ratio = DIVIDE(SUM(Number_3[Count]),
               CALCULATE(SUM(Number_3[Count]),
                         ALL(Number_3[Status]),
                         Number_3[Status] = "Submitted"))
```

Notice how I have a `SUM` aggregation in the numerator instead of a naked column name. The `ALL` function is there so statuses other than `Submitted` return a percentage as well.

Comment: Perfect. I also tried to use a measure instead of a calculated column, but the way I Construct it didn't give me correct result.  Thank you very much